# Optimise processing of for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I have this basic dataframe:

```
     dur    type    src    dst
0     0     new     543     1
1     0     new     21      1
2     1     old     4828    2
3     0     new     321     1
...
(total 450000 rows)
```

My aim is to replace the values in src with either 0, 1 or 2 depending on the values. I created a for loop/if else below:

```
for i in df['src']:
    if i <= 1000:
        df['src'].replace(to_replace = [i], value = [1], inplace = True)
    elif i <= 2500:
        df['src'].replace(to_replace = [i], value = [2], inplace = True)
    elif i <= 5000:
        df['src'].replace(to_replace = [i], value = [3], inplace = True)
    else:
        print('End!')
```

The above works as intended, but it is *awfully slow* trying to replace the entire dataframe with 450000 rows (it is taking more than 30 minutes to do this!).

Is there a more Pythonic way to speed up this algorithm?

Comment: Use a nested `where` Or `cut`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [numpy.select](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjFzr_Nl8buAhXiX3wKHVCsBXgQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnumpy.org%2Fdoc%2Fstable%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.select.html&usg=AOvVaw1Qy8n8VUClc_ZVC1Xf725k), for multiple conditions:

```
cond1 = df.src.le(1000)
cond2 = df.src.le(2500)
cond3 = df.src.le(5000)

condlist = [cond1, cond2, cond3]
choicelist = [1, 2, 3]
df.assign(src=np.select(condlist, choicelist))

    dur     type    src     dst
0   0   new     1   1
1   0   new     1   1
2   1   old     3   2
3   0   new     1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but I think this should work

```py
pd.cut(df.src,  [0, 1000, 2500, 5000], labels=[1,2,3] )
```